# Phonegap 3.4 doesn't copy android to platforms folder (ubuntu 12)

Tags: android, linux, cordova

I have seen different flavours of this question being discussed in the forum.
Excuse me for re-posting it because I have tried all the options discussed without any luck :(

My Env
OS : ubuntu 12
Phonegap : 3.4
Android SDK : 19

Have installed cordova separately as well

Steps I have followed
1)Created project using phonegap create command

```
shaiju@shaiju:~/workspace/adt$ phonegap create HelloWorld
[phonegap] created project at /home/shaiju/workspace/adt/HelloWorld
```

2)Changed to directory HelloWorld

```
shaiju@shaiju:~/workspace/adt$ cd HelloWorld/
shaiju@shaiju:~/workspace/adt/HelloWorld$
```

3) build using phonegap build command for android

```
shaiju@shaiju:~/workspace/adt/HelloWorld$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
```

No error thrown , but the platform folder is empty. Nothing has created there :(

I have tried similar steps using cordova command as well to get the same result

Also tried running the step 3 above with "local" keyword to force the local build. Same result :(

What am I missing here ?

Do we have a bug in phonegap 3.4 on ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Shaiju